# php- Fatal Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $store_list = array();
    $this->db->select('user_time');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('staff_id',$userid);
    $result = $this->db->get();

    $result= $result->result();
    foreach($result as $rows){
        array_push($store_list, $rows["user_time"]);
    }
    return $store_list;
```

I have written a function in a model which contains the above-mentioned code which fetches user's time when user's id passed as a parameter and returns user's time it to the controller function.

But I'm getting the following error: `Fatal Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

What's causing this error? Any ideas?

Note: the sql query returns all matched records. It can be one or more than one records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be `$result` it is object not array, use like this

```
array_push($store_list, $rows->user_time);
```

Comment: User this $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();

Comment: also put a check before using foreach loop like this if ($result) { foreach..... }

Answer (score 1):

The error is because

```
$result= $result->result();
```

here `$result` is an Std Class object, to access its element use `->` instead of `[]` like:

```
array_push($store_list, $rows->user_time);
```

Or to use to use it like an array:

```
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```